# Tables data not scrolling under div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to scroll tables data when it's height is on auto. But its not scrolling the tables data. I want it is to be scroll table instead of div. This is my code

```
<style>
table tr td{background:#ffcc00; padding:10px}
</style>

<div style="position:absolute; height:auto; min-height:200px; overflow-y:scroll; width:100%; top: 130px; left: 0px; padding-bottom:30px;">
       <table style="width:100%; height:auto">
       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       <td>fdsfd</td>
       </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the container `min-height`, you should set `max-height`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kL3MY/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="table_wrapper">
    <!-- Your table goes here -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table_wrapper {
    position:absolute; 
    height:auto;
    max-height:200px; 
    overflow-y:scroll; 
    width:100%; 
    top: 130px; 
    left: 0px; 
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

Am not sure why you are using `position: absolute;` for your `div` element, but I don't think you would need it, but if you want to use it for some reason, than consider nesting the element inside a `position: relative;` container

Comment: @SuRajPrince don't use `position: absolute;`